# How to list number of keys in dictionary with exclusions

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

Interested in the "total" output to reflect the count of new keys matching the criteria in the if statement. If you would also be able to provide instruction on how to show how many keys weren't returned as a result of the if statement that would be helpful.

```
d = {1:0.3246, 2:3.222, 3:3344, 2:0.3444, 5:1.09, 6:222.3}


for key in list(d)[:4]:
    if key == 2:
        continue
    print(key, d[key])
keyresults = key
print('Total unique keys found:', keyresults)
```

Expected results:

```
1 0.3246
3 3344
5 1.09
Total unique keys found: 3
Total unique keys not found: 2
```

Actual results:

```
1 0.3246
3 3344
5 1.09
Total unique keys found: 5
```

Comment: you can not have such a dictionary, can't

Comment: Your current code just prints the *last* key you iterated over. It's unclear why you thought it implemented the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Use `defaultdict` of `collections` module for having duplicate keys.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I realize that. I'm looking for a proper solution. Relatively new to python.

Comment: @Williamct python doesn't allow to create a duplicate dictionary key. dictionary key alway is unique.

Comment: You can just do `len(d.keys())` - As said above, keys *must* be unique

Comment: @bharatk thank you for the response. I appreciate the clarification as again I'm relatively new to python.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at your code example it looks like you are having troubling filtering a list. If you are really looking for duplicate keys then it will be a long search :)

You can filter a dict with a dict-comprehension as follows:

`filtered_dict = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k != 2}`

then you can just call `len()` for the number of *unique* keys. Double keys in a dict are not possible.

```
d = {1:0.3246, 2:3.222, 3:3344, 2:0.3444, 5:1.09, 6:222.3}
print(len(d))  #  = 5, duplicate keys are void

filtered_dict = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k != 2}
print(len(filtered_dict))  #  = 4, since key 2 is dropped.
```

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary which you have declared is "assigned" sequentially. By the time the key is reused with new value, the python interpeter deletes old value for that key and replaces it with the new one. Thus, you can't have same value mapped to two keys. However, defaultdict can help you with two keys scenario. In that scenario, use `set` to get uniquely identifiable keys and mark the duplicates. Now, that being said, which one is actual and which one is duplicate is totally up for interpretation.

here, the factory for default-dict is list, where values are created as list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list)
for k,v in l:
      d[k].append(v)
dict(d)
{1: [111, 'aaa'], 2: [222, 'bbb'], 3: [333, 'ccc']}
```